# VirtualBox: can't get full screen for my Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox

When I first installed, I got Ubuntu running in full screen and I have been using it for quite some time now. But something happened to today, now I'm not getting full screen.

I have tried installing **VirtualBox Guest Additions**, but I'm still stuck with a small window.

-------Update------

I just noticed that I can't use internet either.

Here is a picture:
[image: virtualbox screenshot]

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: yes...thanks for your time and effort..but the problem was an another software that I had installed name 'Droid x' . I uninstalled droidx and reinstalled vbox. and guest additions. and it worked then

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your settings in the bios for hypervisor / VT-x / AMD-v mode. 
On some systems it will randomly get disabled.

After changing or enabling those settings, save, exit, then when it exits, hold the power button and power off the system.

Reboot your PC, go to Virtual Box, check and see that the VM is NOT set at 32bit but 64bit ( Assuming you are using 64bit), Power on VM.

Not sure that is your same issue, but I had a Dell Laptop that did this often to me.